# Python boto3 code to get the matrics from aws cloudwatch

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-cdk

I am working on a `boto3` library and getting some metrics from aws cloud service cloud watch and that works perfectly fine, however, I am placing this question just in anticipation to get a review and guidelines form the python experts to make this code more explicit and distinct for readers so I can also get the opportunity to improve going forward.

```
import boto3
import os
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

# Clients should be created outside of the request handler
fsx = boto3.client('fsx')
cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
ses = boto3.client('ses')
region_name = os.environ['AWS_REGION']
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name=region_name)

# Lambda handler function
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  now = datetime.utcnow()
  start_time = (now - timedelta(minutes=5)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
  end_time = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
  filesystem_ids = []
  result = []
  next_token = None

  # get all filesystem_ids
  while True:
    if next_token:
      response = fsx.describe_file_systems(NextToken=next_token)
    else:
      response = fsx.describe_file_systems()
    for filesystem in response.get('FileSystems'):
      filesystem_id = filesystem.get('FileSystemId')
      filesystem_ids.append(filesystem_id)
    next_token = response.get('NextToken')
    if not next_token:
      break

  try:
    # Create the DynamoDB table if it does not exist
    # Don't keep `dbtable` outside the as it will through an error like "local variable 'dbtable' referenced before assignment"!
    dbtable = dynamodb.Table('hwde-fsxn-fs-monitoring')
    dbtable = dynamodb.create_table(
      TableName='hwde-fsxn-fs-monitoring',
      KeySchema=[
        {
          'AttributeName': 'filesystem_id',
          'KeyType': 'HASH'
        }
      ],
      AttributeDefinitions=[
        {
          'AttributeName': 'filesystem_id',
          'AttributeType': 'S'
        }
      ],
      ProvisionedThroughput={
        'ReadCapacityUnits': 10,
        'WriteCapacityUnits': 10
        }
    )
    # Wait for the table to be created
    dbtable.meta.client.get_waiter(
      'table_exists').wait(TableName='hwde-fsxn-fs-monitoring')
  except ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] != 'ResourceInUseException':
      raise

  # Code to retrieve metric data and check if alert needs to be sent
  for filesystem_id in filesystem_ids:
    response = cloudwatch.get_metric_data(
      MetricDataQueries=[
        {
          'Id': 'm1',
          'MetricStat': {
            'Metric': {
              'Namespace': 'AWS/FSx',
              'MetricName': 'StorageCapacity',
              'Dimensions': [
                {
                  'Name': 'FileSystemId',
                  'Value': filesystem_id
                },
                {
                  'Name': 'StorageTier',
                  'Value': 'SSD'
                },
                {
                  'Name': 'DataType',
                  'Value': 'All'
                }
              ]
          },
            'Period': 60,
            'Stat': 'Sum'
          },
          'ReturnData': True
        },
        {
          'Id': 'm2',
          'MetricStat': {
            'Metric': {
              'Namespace': 'AWS/FSx',
              'MetricName': 'StorageUsed',
              'Dimensions': [
                {
                  'Name': 'FileSystemId',
                  'Value': filesystem_id
                },
                {
                  'Name': 'StorageTier',
                  'Value': 'SSD'
                },
                {
                  'Name': 'DataType',
                  'Value': 'All'
                }
              ]
            },
            'Period': 60,
            'Stat': 'Sum'
          },
          'ReturnData': True
        }
      ],
      StartTime=start_time,
      EndTime=end_time
    )
    storage_capacity = response['MetricDataResults'][0]['Values']
    storage_used = response['MetricDataResults'][1]['Values']

    if storage_capacity:
      storage_capacity = storage_capacity[0]
    else:
      storage_capacity = None
    if storage_used:
      storage_used = storage_used[0]
    else:
      storage_used = None
    if storage_capacity and storage_used:
      percent_used = (storage_used / storage_capacity) * 100
    else:
      percent_used = None
    
    ######################################################################
    #### Check if an alert has already been sent for this filesystem_id ###
    #######################################################################
    _dbQuery = dbtable.get_item(Key={'filesystem_id': filesystem_id})
    if 'Item' in _dbQuery:
      alert_sent = _dbQuery['Item']['alert_sent']
      print("E-mail has been sent for the filesystem {}:".format(filesystem_id))
    else:
      alert_sent = False
      print("E-mail has not been sent for the filesystem {}:".format(filesystem_id))
    # Send an alert if storage usage exceeds the threshold and no alert has been sent yet
    if percent_used > 85 and not alert_sent:
      result.append({'filesystem_id': filesystem_id, 'percent_used': percent_used})

  if result:
    header = f'''
        Dear Team,<br><br> Please find the FSx ONTAP filesystem(SSD Tier) threshold breached report below for the {region_name} region, Kindly check the alert and increase the filesystem if required or act accordingly.
       <br></br>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <th style='text-align: left'>FileSystemId</th>
        <th style='text-align: right'>Used %</th>
       </tr>
    '''
    body = ""

    for fs in result:
        body += f'''
          <tr>
            <td style='text-align: left'>{fs['filesystem_id']}</td>
            <td style='text-align: right; color:red;'>{str(round(fs['percent_used'], 2))}%</td>
          </tr>
          '''
    footer = f'''</table>
                  <br></br>
                  Sincerely,<br>
                  Storage CIS Team.
              '''
    email_body = header + body + footer
    if not alert_sent:
        ses.send_email(
           Source='botoassist@example.com',
           Destination={
               'ToAddresses': ['some-email@example.com']
           },
           Message={
               'Subject': {
               'Data': "FSx ONTAP filesystem alert report for {} region.".format(region_name)
               },
               'Body': {
                   'Html': {
                       'Data': email_body
                    }
              }
           }
        )
        for fs in result:
            filesystem_id = fs['filesystem_id']
            dbtable.put_item(
                Item = {
                     'filesystem_id': filesystem_id,
                     'alert_sent': True
                    }
            )
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps('Email sent!')
        }
```

Thank you so much in advanced and a very happy new year!

Comment: Don't write redundant comments, e.g. "lambda handler function". Conform to [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008) using [black -S .](https://pypi.org/project/black) with default 4 spaces, _not_ 2. Each function should be visible on one screen without scrolling, so this one is _much too long_. Now I know that some of the lines are for boring well-formatted API args -- consider evicting those to helper functions, rather than mixing such unchanging data with your program logic. In particular you really need a `def _get_metric_data(filesystem_id):` helper. Also: "alert" helper(s).

Comment: @-J_H, thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, remember that *one function (or class), one responsibility* is a good rule of thumb when designing software. Furthermore, in general, variables should be declared as late as possible and as close to their site of use as possible: if a variable like `result` is declared at the beginning of a function and used only tens of lines later, that's a code smell and not only hurts readability but also makes it susceptible to errors.

The first tip in [Best practices for working with AWS Lambda functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html) is to separate the Lambda handler from your core logic. Indeed, I get a strong urge to find logical pieces of your current solution and break it down to smaller pieces that are individually testable and usable. You could look at the lambda handler as doing (at least) these steps:

1. Get filesystem IDs.
2. Build a DynamoDB table.
3. For each filesystem ID, get corresponding CloudWatch metric data.
4. Build a list of alerts to notify the users.
5. Prepare and format an email to be sent.
6. Send an email and do logging.

All this in a single lambda handler is very difficult to read and reason about.

Start by cutting out pieces of logic from your lambda handler. I recommend you approach this with [test-driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) in mind. So for each, write a unit test and

- a function that gathers all FSx filesystem IDs, and
- a function that, given a filesystem id, gets the corresponding CloudWatch metric data.

You can further use a helper function that prepares the metric data query. After this, I would keep going and write a function that receives the required parameters, and prepares an email body to be sent. I would also consider if the lambda function really needs to create the DynamoDB table: could you create this somewhere outside the lambda function completely and let the lambda handler just use it? Here, remember that it's best practice to pass details such as table names to a lambda via environment variables (again, see the link provided).

I hope this gets you going, it sounds like a fun exercise to implement all this and refactor the handler so that it's more readable, maintainable and testable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, i am not very well versed in python so trying learn bit by bit, i will try work upon the guided principles. I would be grateful if someone can give me the sketch on how to write them so as to follow them +1.